# Error propagation in chained Promise not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I'm learning chaining in JS Promises from [this site.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Error_propagation) Based on the high level example, I've written following code to understand error propagation better.

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('Rejected!');
});

promise.then(()=>new Promise ((resolve, reject) => resolve('Done!')), () => console.log('Failure of first Promise'))
       .then(() => console.log('Success of nested Promise'), () => console.log('Failure of nested Promise'));

console.log('This will be still printed first!');
```

Here when I'm rejecting the first promise, It is giving logging `Failure of first Promise` and then `Success of nested Promise`.

Now I wonder how It's going in the success callback of nested Promise? As  explained in the above mentioned article, it's clear that even one promise is failed (rejected), the failure callback should be invoked.

What I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Rethrow the error if it needs to propagate down `error => throw error;` or throw a new error inside the rejection handlers if you need to change some of the error objects properties. `error => throw new Error( 'some other error description' );`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written is like

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject('Rejected!'); });
promise
    .then(()=>new Promise ((resolve, reject) => resolve('Done!')))
    .catch(() => console.log('Failure of first Promise'))
    .then(() => console.log('Success of nested Promise'))
    .catch(() => console.log('Failure of nested Promise')); 
    console.log('This will be still printed first!');
```

since `catch` also returns a promise, the `then` chained with `catch` will also be triggered, if there is only one `catch` at end of all `then`, that catch will be triggered without any `then`.

you can do the following to overcome this issue,

```
promise
    .then(()=>new Promise ((resolve, reject) => resolve('Done!')))
    .then(() => console.log('Success of nested Promise'))
    .catch(() => console.log('Failure of Promise')); 
    console.log('This will be still printed first!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Second `then` callback catches the error from previous promise (catches as in `try..catch`). *In this specific case* (there's no chance that first `then` callbacks result in rejection) this is the same as:

```
promise // rejected promise
.then(()=>new Promise ((resolve, reject) => resolve('Done!'))) // skips rejected promise
.catch(() => console.log('Failure of first Promise')) // results in resolved promise
.then(() => console.log('Success of nested Promise')) // chains resolved promise
.catch(() => console.log('Failure of nested Promise')); // skips resolved promise
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because

> The catch() method returns a Promises

[MDN source - Promise.prototype.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

```
"use strict";

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject('Error');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(`Failed because of ${err}`);
}).then(() => {
  console.log('This will be called since the promise returned by catch() is resolved');
});
```

This will log

> Failed because of Error
>   This will be called since the promise returned by catch() is resolved